# Insect Identification. Moth or dragonfly or?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found on the exterior wall of my house taking cover from the rain it seems. Wingspan is approximately 5cm. I live in the South SF Bay and it has been rather cold and rainy this week.

[image: Flies like a moth. Sits like a dragonfly.]

Comment: t has two long cerci, so I guess it can't be a crane fly, an odonate (dragonflies and damselflies) or a moth/butterfly. It has winged hair but it really does not look like a caddisfly. The butt seems to come back up but it does not look like a mecoptera (scorpion fly). This thing look like the wings can't move, like a plane! Was it alive? Did you notice any behaviour? Can you say anything about the mouth part?  I think I would think those arenot cerci and it is some kind of moth.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Found it. [Amblyptilia acanthadactyla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblyptilia_acanthadactyla) from Europe. He must be tired.</strike>

**Update:** It's a [Geranium Plume Moth](https://bugguide.net/node/view/48046)! Beautiful [pics](https://www.plumemoth.com/)! I have geranium plants in my garden. Why have I never seen these? Thanks for the right find, [Arthur](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/32396/arthur-j-frost)!

Comment: Oohh a plume moth. That would make sense. Probably a sister species given that you found it in the USA. It could be a *[Geina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geina) sp.* maybe or some other plume moth.

Comment: Could be! And it's alive, btw. I carefully captured it safely in a jar before having identified it. Since it doesn't eat people or pets, I have set it free to enjoy the low growing plants in my garden. Thanks for playing, Remi.b

Comment: Agreed as to the family; the genus as given originally _is_ possible (according to [this site](https://www.plumemoth.com/) the genus has two species north of Mexico); it doesn't look like all Nearctic species have images online (the site I just linked to does have a few photos accompanying a fairly recent species checklist [the most recently described species therein dates from 2017] and does link to other sites with photos).

Comment: Could you add an image and some backgrounds why you think this is the correct ID? Such as global distribution and whether it fits OP's location and so forth.

Comment: The species as given in the answer is not correct; the genus might be ([bugguide's coverage of a Nearctic congener here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/7000/bgpage) does look similar -- and the species is Californian); I would upvote the answer if it were changed to that species.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost I think you owe Johnny an upvote :p